# find total change in temperature of a person being struck by lighning

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, phase-transition

A lightning flash releases about 1010J of electrical energy.

If all this energy is added to 50 kg of water (the amount of water in a 165-lb person) at 37∘C, what are the final state and temperature of the water? The specific heat of water is 4180 J/kg⋅∘C, heat of vaporization at the boiling temperature for water is 2.256×106J/kg, the specific heat of steam is 1970 J/kg⋅∘C

Find ΔT in ∘C

I found
Qwater = (50kg)(4180J/kg⋅∘C)(100-37) = 1.13167⋅10^7 J
Qphase change to steam = (50kg)(2.256×106J/kg) = 1.128⋅10^8 J
Qtotal = 1.13167⋅10^7 J + 1.128⋅10^8 J = 1.25967⋅10^8 J

I'm not sure what to do with the energy from the lightning strike in order to find the total change in temperature.

I tried putting the different of Qtotal and the energy from the lighting into the ΔU = Q-W equation, but I ended up with a temperature difference over 10k which isn't right and not even possible for water.

Comment: it would be helpful if you told me what's unclear or somewhere to look instead of down voting it. I've spent over a week trying to answer this problem on my own and I haven't found anything. I've found nothing about adding a certain amount of energy to a system and trying to find another variable from it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have already calculated the energy required to raise the temperature of 50 kg  to the boiling point. It is significantly higher than the amount of energy in a bolt of lightning, so the steps after that are not necessary. You can look at the units to guess that $\Delta T=\frac{E}{Cm},$ where $C$ is the specific heat, $m$ is the mass, and $E$ is the energy transferred from the lightning bolt.

Comment: so pretty much none of the calculation I did were even needed and they just gave me a bunch of numbers for the hell of it.. Thank you for your response.